# VMWare Fusion shuts down VM when display turns off

Tags: windows-10, vmware-fusion

We're using VMWare Fusion 8.5.3, and the "Microsoft Edge on Win 10 Stable" virtual machine from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/.

Whenever the host machine turns off the display it shuts down the virtual machine. Not just suspending, a full startup happens on resume. This all happens despite both the host and guest operating system being set to never go to sleep:

[image: host os settings]
[image: guest os settings]

Since the host is a MacBook, I really don't want to have the screen on all the time. And we use the shared folders feature of VMWare, so we can't just disable the service.

Are there any other things I could try?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Our issue was because the Windows VM needed to be reactivated. There should be instructions on the Desktop to guide you through that process.

Comment: But if that's not working, I also wrote a `vm-keepalive` script to start the VM if it's not already running.